# Meta tags changes do not appear on the facebook like button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, meta-tags

I use the meta tags in the exact way the instructions say. So when I click on the like button, I indeed have the correct information on my facebook page.

Yet, when I slightly change the meta tags' code (for example if I put another image or if I change the description) the changes do not take effect on the facebook like button, which continues to show the previous information.

This is very disturbing, because by mistake I put same link in the *meta property="og:url"* for two different pages, so when someone likes one of them, the other ones like button is also "pushed". And although I've corrected the code, the problem with the like button, as I said before, remains.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to edit your Open Graph tags at any time.  The only exception is title is fixed after 50 likes and type after 10k

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#edit

Facebook has to scrape your pages to see the changes to the Open Graph tags.  You can force this by using the debugger/linter.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no way to fix my mistake until a lot of people have clicked like on the wrong page?

Also, the debugger sees the right information/url of the like button, but when someone likes the page they still see the previous information. I can't understand why that happens...

Comment: No I'm just saying that Facebooks documentation says it should be possible to fix your mistake. When you rescrape the page the new Open Graph tags should be posted when you click like. Is the href attribute correct on the malfunctioning button?